# How to perform a series of multiplication with one of the multiplier as the product from earlier in pandas without looping?

Tags: python, pandas

The code that is in a for loop would be

```
    original = 1
    results = []
    multiplier = [5, 7, 30, 2, 8]
    for i in multiplier:
      original = original * i
      results.append(original)
```

how would we translate this in a pandas dataframe without looping?

So the result I want would be a dataframe looking like this

| multiplier | results |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 |
| 7 | 45 |
| 30 | 1350 |
| 2 | 2700 |
| 8 | 21600 |

Answer (score 1):

Sure, `cumprod` is what you're looking for here.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'nums':[5, 7, 30, 2, 8]})

df['results'] = df['nums'].cumprod()
print(df)
```

That'll give you:

```
   nums  results
0     5        5
1     7       35
2    30     1050
3     2     2100
4     8    16800
```